# Can Rimuru's Predator power put someone in an infinite dream?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

Can Rimuru somehow create an infinite dream for those he eats, for example when he used Predator on Shizu and she saw her mom?

Comment: I don't think so because ifrit and veldora wasn't in a dream but just in a black hole

Comment: Oh I guess that makes sense but couldn't he just as easily put some in the black hole and others in an infinite dream I mean I think rimuru said something that made me think that I think it was something about her being in a dream or something

Comment: I think she is in heaven because she died...

Comment: Okay I guess that would make sense

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so because the ones that are consumed(not confined like Ifrit or Veldora) are eaten soul and all. It is revealed in the novel series that the times that Shizu appears (after being eaten) is due to the leftovers of her soul. Thus I don't think Rimuru can put someone in an infinite dream, as he would have done that for Shizu if he could

Comment: Please indicate specifically the references used (chapter, light novel volume, anime episode, etc).